# How to overlay a png to piped video source with audio mixed in via ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm successfully streaming silent video with music added from my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) to YouTube via ffmpeg, with the help of [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/maxogden/69e4ae18a32d7efd00d9) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/how-to-add-a-new-audio-not-mixing-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg):

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -b 4000000 | \
ffmpeg -i music.wav \
-f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental \
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAMKEY
```

The last step of my project to add a transparent, full width/height png overlay to the video (1280x720 size in my case). I've seen a few related answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251122/using-ffmpeg-to-add-overlay-with-opacity) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480153/how-to-overlay-place-an-image-on-a-video-in-ffmpeg).

With the added complexity of piping in a camera feed, mixing in an audio source and outputting to a video stream, I haven't succeeded in adding the image overlay. Where/how would I add a transparent image overlay in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ffmpeg part will be

```
ffmpeg -i music.wav \
-f h264 -i - -i overlay.png
-filter_complex "[1][2]overlay"
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental \
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAMKEY
```

Since you're altering the video contents, `copy` can't be used, and the video has to be re-encoded.

Comment: @ChristopherStevens You won't need `-strict experimental` unless your ffmpeg is quite old, and for streaming I recommend [adding `-maxrate`, `-bufsize`, and optionally `-b:v`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you for the additional thoughts. With those suggested edits, all is working well. Your link was very helpful.